# Disable YouTube autoplay permanently (no cookies) in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, youtube

I am trying to disable the obnoxious AutoPlay anti-feature in YouTube running in Firefox. I do not sign into Firefox, nor do I allow YouTube to use cookies on my machine, so the Autoplay slider button is not a working option for me.

I notice that it seems to be JavaScript controlled, so I tried adding the following filters to AdBlock Plus:

```
*innertube_watchnext*
*www\watch_autoplayrenderer.js*
```

However, neither of these filters seems to disable it. Does anyone have any further suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried any extension to stop autoplay in firefox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autoplay feature is located in a JavaScript file called `watch_autoplayrenderer.js` that is loaded from `https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-en_US-vflSyOHa7/watch_autoplayrenderer.js`. Filtering for

```
||ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/*/watch_autoplayrenderer.js$important
```

therefore works. Note that the `$important` is important because EasyList explicitly whitelists scripts from that server:

```
@@||ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/$script
```

Comment: $important appears to be a uBlock option; I use AdBlock Plus, is there an equivalent for AdBlock?

Comment: I have got this to work by simply disabling the ytimg exception. Thanks very much.